# How to get folder path runtime

Tags: file

I am new to java.

I am using this code

```
MyClass.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("myfile.properties")
```

to the values from property file.

Now i am storing the webdriver in a folder under project, would like to get the path dybamically, so im using this code:

```
MyClass.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("Drivers\\IEDriverServer_x64_2.50.0.zip")
```

but this returns null, can any one suggest me how to read the file/folder located under the project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all check the location of the file you want to load inside the JAR and try using relative paths like

```
MyClass.class.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/yourFolder/myfile.properties")
```

**OR**

```
MyClass.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/yourFolder/myfile.properties")
```

Comment: @ Krishna,
thanks for your comment, do i need to store the o/p in InpustStream variable? when i execute with relative path also i get the null output.
used both InputStream & String variables

Comment: See your file structure `myfile.properties` needs to be in inside yourFolder under `src`. Then after clean the project, Rebuild it and try again.

Comment: sorry, i was not clear in putting my qn. i was able to read the data from property file fine.

wanted to do the same to read the IE driver location path, which is placed under src.
to do this, when i used InputStream & String variable both return null below is the code im using:
String 
String local=MyClass.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/Drivers/IEDriverServer_x64_2.50.0.zip").toString();

Comment: If you want to read files inside the zip you have to consider another way else try using [getResources()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource(java.lang.String))  method. which will return URL